# Background text in title sequence of The 100?

Tags: the-100

Starting in season 2, the opening title sequences of *The 100* highlight features of the scenery with text overlays. I can't get enough resolution to read the majority of them; are they meaningful or random, and are there legible versions anywhere out there?

Example below, but there are multiple cases throughout each title sequence.

[image: Screen image from opening sequence of the 100 showing a desolate landscape with blurred text overlaid]

Comment: Some of that stuff is written in symbols I don't recognise, and some of it is just too small to see. I can see a number of things written in English though, in [this somewhat higher-res screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcXxb.jpg). From left-to-right, starting near the bottom-middle of the image, I read "CATALOGING IN PROGRESS", "OFFERING GROVE", "RYKER'S KEEP", "INNER SANCTUM", and "RADITION TOWER PERIMETER".

Comment: Yes - this particular capture was just an example. There's a whole set of them through the title sequences; a few bigger and clearer, and a lot that look like they might say something coherent but too small to make out on screen.

Comment: I haven't watched this series, so I can't put this stuff in context with the story, but it looks to me like this text is meant to signify areas of the Earth's surface being systematically scanned, mapped, and catalogued. That "CATALOGING IN PROGRESS" line appears several times in the sequence. Another phrase I see on one screen is "ANOMALY DETECTED".

Comment: I'm looking at the opening titles on Youtube and the vast majority of bits of text seem to be perfectly legible; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFa7_OK5vFQ